# Difference between open ball and open cover

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have  some confusion about the difference between   open ball and open cover

Take  discrete metrics space  $( \mathbb{R} , d)$  where $d= \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if } x \ \neq y \\ 0 \ \text{if }x=y \end{cases}
$

$B(x,r) = \begin {cases} \{x\}\ \text{if} \ r \le 1 \\ \mathbb{R} \ \text{if} \ r >1 \end{cases}$

If i take union of open ball  $B(x,r)$ then $\bigcup(B(x_i,r) =\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty} \{x_i\}$

Now open cover  of $( \mathbb{R} , d)= \{ \{x\} :  x \in \mathbb{R}\}= \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty \{x_i\}$

My doubts is that  Is  union of open ball is equal to open cover  in  $( \mathbb{R} , d)?$

Comment: A collection of open sets whose union contains $A$ is an open cover of $A$

Comment: The title was better than the content of the question. After the edit, it is worse. A ball is a ball and a cover is a cover. These are totally different things. Like a nail and a coffin.

Comment: Whether an open ball is a cover depends on the set you are trying to cover. It sometimes helps to separate concepts if you have a range of examples in mind. What examples of a cover do you know?

Comment: @MarkBennet open cover of $(1,2)$ is $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 +\frac{1}{n}, 2-\frac{1}{n} \right)$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space then the open ball around $x\in X$ of radius $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is defined as

$$B(x,r):=\{y\in X\ |\ d(x,y)<r\}$$

And so it is a subset of $X$ by definition.

On the other hand an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is by definition a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that their union is $X$. And so $\mathcal{U}$ **is not** a subset of $X$, but it is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ = the collection of all subsets of $X$.

So if we have $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric then indeed any singleton $\{x\}$ is an open ball. And $\mathbb{R}$ itself is also an open ball as you've correctly noticed.

And then $\mathcal{U}=\big\{\{x\}\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\big\}$ would be an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $\mathcal{U}$ is not an open ball, it is not even a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it is a special collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Perhaps the difference is easier to grasp if we look at a finite metric space, say $X=\{1,2\}$ with the discrete metric. Then the following are all possible open balls (and in fact all possible nonempty open subsets):

$$\{1\},\ \{2\},\ \{1,2\}$$

which are all possible singletons together with $X$, analogously to what you've described for $\mathbb{R}$. And the following are all possible open covers:

$$\{\{1\},\{2\}\},\ \{\{1,2\}\},\ \{\{1,2\}, \{1\}\},\ \{\{1,2\},\{2\}\},\ \{\{1,2\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$$

> My doubts is that  Is  union of open ball is equal to open cover  in  $( \mathbb{R} , d)?$

No, not union. Collection.